# what is the video format that gives 1mb per 1minute?

Tags: video, compression, formats

what is the video format that gives 1mb per 1minute ??

regards,
Buffon

Comment: At the minimum, bitrate says nothing without desired resolution, FPS, precision (24-bit color), the kind of color space used.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your demanded resolution and/or image quality. You can't say that generally.

Comment: ok what's the best format for compression ??

Comment: DivX, H.264, Xvid... It also depends on the type of the video ;-) You should try it with some free video conversion tools.